# Why is Tyrian purple called 6,6′-dibromoindigo?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, heterocyclic-compounds, dye

If the two bromines are attached at opposite ends of the molecule, why are they both labelled with a 6?

Also, why is 6,6′-dibromoindigo not called 1,1′-dibromoindigo if carbons in a ring are numbered according to their substituents, and bromine is the substituent, therefore the carbon it is attached to should be called 1, not 6?

[image: Structure of Tyrian purple]

Comment: Because of [Indole numbering](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indole): N is 1 and the other atoms (except the C that bridges both rings) are numbered in ascending order, so the Br substituent is at position 6 in both rings.

Comment: Br atoms are not both numbered 6. The other one is 6', where the apostrophe means the same position but on the other indol structure.

Comment: Beside the above comments, rings numbering is always, although "fixed" and coded, quite a "mess".